# aurelia-validation with custom element

Tags: custom-element, aurelia

I created an input form with aurelia-validation plugin which worked perfectly.
Now I created a custom element to replace the input type textbox.
I'm trying to validate the new custom element value, by setting the value attribute with the "validate"  keyword - but the custom element input value isn't validated.
It seems like the Validation Controller is not binded to the custom element.
The bindings array of the Validation Controller doesn't contains the custom element.
**Maybe this is related to the actions that should trigger the validation (blur\focus out), so I  added dispatching of blur event, but it still doesn't work. As mentioned - it worked perfectly when it was a regular element.**
Here is the relevant code (un-needed code was removed):
custom element template:

```
<template>
    <label>
        ${title}<input name.bind="fieldName" 
        title.bind="title" focusout.trigger="focusoutAction()" />
    </label>
</template>
```

custom element relevant viewmodel code:

```
 @bindable onFocusout;
 ...
 bind(bindingContext) {
 var input = this.element.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
 input.type = this.customType || "text";
 input.placeholder = this.placeHolder || "";
 //input.value.bind = bindingContext.registration.firstName & validate;
 }
 ...
 focusoutAction() {
   var customEvent = new CustomEvent("blur");
   this.element.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
   this.onFocusout(); 
 }
```

Relevant container(parent) view code:

```
<form-input name="firstName" id="firstName" title="First Name" bind-
value="registration.firstName & validate" field-name="firstName" on-
focusout.call="validateInput()" />
```

And the relevant viewmodel code:

```
ValidationRules
.ensure(r => r.firstName).displayName('first 
name').required().withMessage(`\${$displayName} cannot be blank`)
.satisfiesRule('FirstNameValidation')
.ensure(r => r.lastName).displayName('last 
name').required().withMessage(`\${$displayName} cannot be blank`)
.satisfiesRule('LastNameValidation')

validateInput() { this.getValidationError(event.target.name); }

getValidationError(propertyName) {
let error = this.getValidationFirstError(propertyName);
....
}
getValidationFirstError(propertyName) 
{
  if (this.controllerToValidate.errors !== null && 
  this.controllerToValidate.errors.length > 0) //This is 0 !!!!!
}
```